# InfoPath 2010: Mirror data from a Secondary Data Source

Tags: dom, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath, infopath2010

**Goal**: Pull data from a SharePoint 2010 List using a WEB ENABLED form. Then, from the repeating table that contains the secondary data, extract only the desired data and mirror it in my main form fields. The extracted data would then be modified, and submitted to another sharepoint list using Nintex Workflows or, if the IT department smiles upon this project, a database.

---

**What I've Tried**: Created a field, named "TEST_CyS", in a repeating group, named "TEST", in my main form fields to store the mirrored data. This field has a default value of:

```
xdXDocument:GetDOM("REMOVED")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW[(count(../preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = "TEST"]) + 1)]/d:Cy_Statement
```

This is refreshed when the form updates.

- If I set the default value to `count(../preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = "TEST"]) + 1` it accurately counts each inserted group.
- if I set the default value to `xdXDocument:GetDOM("REMOVED")/dfs:myFields/dfs:dataFields/d:SharePointListItem_RW[<INT>])]/d:Cy_Statement` where `<INT>` is any whole value between 1 and n then the field will display the correct information, for the secondary data field whose index is referenced.

It's when I combine the two that things fall apart.

***Main Data Tree:***

[image: Main Data Set]

***Secondary Data Tree:***

[image: Secondary Data Set]

---

**Assumptions:** I am guessing that the `preceding-sibling::*[local-name() = "TEST"]` axis is not returning a value due to the fact that it's being called along with the `GetDOM()` method. I've tried to point the preceding-sibling back to the correct group in the Main form fields, but then I felt silly for trying that as it wouldn't know where to start counting AND infopath presented me with an error:

```
Function 'GetDOM' did not return a value, or it returned a value that cannot be converted to an XSL data type.
```

**Summary:** Is this a lost cause without code or purchasing some "plugin" for Infopath like qRules? The IT department will not budge on allowing Forms with code in them to be run on the SharePoint site, and the requirements placed on the form state that it must be a web enabled form to be filled out in SharePoint.

Edit: We also do not have access to VSTA, and the possibility of having it installed is very, very slim.

***Is there an alternative method I could use to pull this off?***

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint admins don't need to be involved if the InfoPath form uses code, so long as it is limited to the SharePoint 2010 sandbox APIs.

Comment: Ah, I failed to mention VSTA is not installed and I'm working on locked down computers. That information is helpful though. I'll try talking to the upper management about getting VSTA installed, but my hopes aren't high. We're working with a lot of boundries here, and being asked for a lot. Thanks!